# How to update sqlite3 to v3.27 on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: sqlite, raspbian, debian-stretch, raspberry-pi-zero

I am running Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi Zero and it has sqlite3 v3.16.2. "sudo apt update sqlite3" says I am on the newest version. Is there a way to update to any newer version?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled v3.34 from source. Seems to work fine. Not sure why apt-get installs v3.16.